# How many combinations are possible?

Tags: combinatorics

Given $n$ spots, in how many ways $4$ spots can be filled with $3$ red balls and $1$ blue ball? 
We may assume that the three red balls are indistinguishable, while considering how many ways the spots can be occupied .

I've tried to solve it and have come up with :-

${n\choose3}  (n-3)$ is it correct, if no please help me with this.

Comment: yes, it seems to be correct :) I hope n>3 always. if not, take extra care about that :)

Comment: Yes its given that n>=4, i.e we atleast have 4 spots :)

Comment: How about $4\binom{n}{4}$ ?

Answer (score 1):

You can pick the spot for the red balls in ${n \choose 3}$ ways.  Having done that, you can pick the spot for the blue ball in $n-3$ ways, because $3$ of the spots are full.  Your calculation is correct.  Another approach is to pick the spot for the blue one in $n$ ways, then you have ${n-1 \choose 3}$ ways to pick the slots for the red ones, giving $n{n-1 \choose 3}$.  These are equal, as we have shown.  You can also show it by expanding the factorials.